# owl carousel not working. already added a js library

Tags: owl-carousel

Hi i have this owl carousel in my site, my problem is i already loaded the owl carousel js library and it seems not working dont know what the problem is. Here is my code below

```
<!-- PARALLAX -->
            <section class="parallax parallax-2" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/particles_bg.jpg');">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="owl-carousel text-center owl-testimonial nomargin" data-plugin-options='{"singleItem": true, "autoPlay": 3000, "navigation": false, "pagination": true}'>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h3 class="nomargin">Popular Products</h3>
                            <p class="font-lato weight-300 lead nomargin-top">Incidunt deleniti blanditiis quas aperiam recusandae consequatur ullam.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h3 class="nomargin">New Products</h3>
                            <p class="font-lato weight-300 lead nomargin-top">Incidunt deleniti blanditiis quas aperiam recusandae consequatur ullam.</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>


            </section>
            <!-- /PARALLAX -->
```

library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/owl.theme.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

can someone help me figured this out? Im stuck on this. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the plugin in your js code... in your case you should call it
in your main.js when all the libs are loaded, so if you do not have main.js created, create it and call the plugin in appropriate way(you also should have jquery library included):
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#more-demos

Official page of owl-carousel.

Comment: im using this template 
http://theme.stepofweb.com/Smarty/v1.1.3/HTML/index-shop-5.html

Comment: Try to call the plugin in the browser console see if that works
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
Also see if there is some error and paste it here